Issues with deleting and reinstalling git completely after hard drive which had Git was corrupt
I have a Windows 11 system, and I have had Git for a long time. I downloaded Git on my internal HDD on my laptop. Recently, my internal HDD got corrupted, and I am not able to access any data in it and will not be able to fix it for a bit. I am also not able to use Git, owing to it being in my HDD.
Wherever I try to download Git on my SSD, it gives me the same error saying:

The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible. Please select another.

after downloading the zip file from the official website. It does not give me an option to select where I want to download it.
I have tried to delete it multiple times. But the error message states:

E:\Git\unins000.exe
The system cannot find the drive specified

I want to delete Git and redownload it on my SSD so that it works normally like before.
here are the steps i followed while trying to setup git and the error i got:
the setup app:

the setup screen:

the prompt to install:

the error:


The error message says that the Git folder was E:\Git – not anything under "Program Files". What kind of disk was E:\ on? Does E:\Git still exist?

"after downloading the zip file from the official website. It does not give me an option to select where I want to download it." Right, becasue the web browser tends to ask you this before it gets fully downloaded. This is a web browser setting, and unrelated to some of the other stuff that was mentioned. Also look to see if C:\Git exists. Otherwise, much more precise detail may be needed for us to understand what you're doing. You might need to edit this question or make another question. Maybe you might attract more relevant answerers if the question mentions "web browser" rather than "Git".

WHAT gives you the error saying the drive or network folder is not available? I'm with TOOGAM right now, and I think you're describing an issue downloading a file, not an issue with Git. Please do what you can to EDIT your post, using very clear terms to describe the applications you are using at each step, and the messages these applications are giving.

@Ramhound the internal hard drive is corrupt.

@grawity The disk was inbuilt and i got it when i bought the computer. it still does exist inside it, but it is corrupt and i cannot access any files in it.

@TOOGAM I am only able to download the Git Setup from the internet. C:\Git does not exist. and it exists on the drive that is now corrupt and inaccessable

As mentioned above, you're describing an issue downloading a file, not an issue with Git.

im sorry if i come out as stupid, but how am i to work around this? @ChanganAuto

Also as suggested above, it's something to do with your browser settings. If you set it to ask where to download stuff I cannot imagine such problems occurring. That's for starters.

@Vrishank - What do you mean by "the disk is inbuilt"?

@Ramhound its a laptop. i had the 1TB hdd hard disk that you get with it for storage. it used to work as the D: drive.

In that case, what was the E: drive? Also, can you try disabling the "Only show new options" checkbox in Git Setup?

@Vrishank - So it's an internal HDD or SSD.  That is expected that your boot drive is an internal HDD or SSD.

First, a bit about the status of this question:
The responses given so far (including my own), up to Ramhound's, seems sensible.
This is not really a good question on SuperUser.  I don't blame the question-asker, who may have simply lacked enough knowledge to be able to ask things in more clear ways.  However, that doesn't change my assessment that the question is currently not good.
A good question in SuperUser (or Stack Exchange) is a rather narrow question, focused on just one topic, so that one or more perfectly clear answers can exist.  When you have multiple topics, then it can become darn-near impossible for a single answer to be not just repeating information seen elsewhere (like in other questions) and answering everything so that the question feels fully satisfied.
In fairness, the question's topic does start saying, "Issues with deleting and reinstalling git completely".  So the question is up-front about it having multiple issues.  But that doesn't change the fact that questions of this nature are discouraged.
Given all that, I suggest taking the information obtained from this question, and making separate brand new questions on SuperUser, as needed.  In each question, do mention some of the background information that is likely relevant, but make sure each "question" on the site is really focused on a single real question/topic.
Multiple Problems:
It seems like we have multiple problems:

The question stated, "Wherever I try to download Git on my SSD, it gives me the same error".  Later, the question was updated with a screenshot, posted after some other screenshots.  I think when this error messsage shows up, the "it" refers to Git's installer.  But, the way this was phrased, it sounds like "the downloading Git" process gives the error, which is why it sounded like a problem with the "web browser".
If there is an issue with downloading and saving to somewhere on E:, the most popular modern day web browsers tend to have the ability to store a location which will be used for downloading a file.  In fact, this is the default behavior.  When downloading a file like that, the browser will not ask where the file goes.  This behavior is based on an option that can be changed, so if you want to change that location on an on-going basis, you can, and if you want to have the web browser ask you for each file, you can.  How to do that will depend on which browser you are using.  Instructions should not be provided here, now, because at the time of this writing, we don't know which browser is being used.  If you want help with that, please identify which web browser you are using (e.g. Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Apple Safari, Microsoft Edge are likely the most popular these days), and then try to find online documentation on how to do that.  If you need further help with that, I advise making a new specific question on SuperUser and make sure to mention which browser to use.
Drive Corruption is also a topic discussed
Another topic is an uninstaller not being found
User wishes to get Git installed

Drive corruption
The end user does mention that the system has a corrupt hard drive.  That likely means there is either a malfunctioning drive, or may mean that the hardware is actually just fine but there is corruption in the filesystem/volume/partition layout.  If you want further help diagnosing that, that would need to be a separate question.  As is, I feel like this has been getting mentioned as possibly-relevant background information, which is a good thing.  Clearly specifying which drive letter this is using, on each new question that might get posted, would be a good thing.
Very quickly, I will mention my preferred way of handling things.  To be clear, when I say "drive", I mean the physical "hard drive", not just a single partition (which Windows might call a drive).  If data can be copied off, that is most preferable.  (Actually, having multiple copies would be preferred, so that there is a reasonably-trustable backup.)  A forensic-style full disk image would be more preferable, if feasible.  Then, once there is no valuable data on the drive, fully performing a drive test is preferable.  That might be best to do before the next step(s) I will mention, although may often be easiest to do after the next step(s), depending on what software is used.  Then, erasing all partitions on the drive will help eliminate any corruption that might exist on a partition.  If the issue isn't hardware-caused, that might fix the problem(s) entirely.  If the issue is hardware-caused, then history tells us that problematic hard drives tend to get worse over time, sometimes dramatically and quickly, so your best bet is to only use the drive if you have a way to use it for temporary data only, and if you are okay with potential system instability.  (As that is often not the case, such drives tend to just get discarded.)  The recommended way to discard is drive is to first get it "wiped" (using software, which might or might not use a hardware-specific feature to help with that).
Cannot Uninstall

I have tried to delete it multiple times. But the error message states:
E:\Git\unins000.exe
The system cannot find the drive specified
I want to delete Git and redownload it on my SSD so that it works normally like before.

Okay, there are multiple possible interpretations of the requested topic here.
It is clear to me, from the reference to E:\Git\unins000.exe, that something is trying to run Git's "uninstaller" program.  For many programs, when they get installed in Microsoft Windows, they register themselves with Microsoft Windows in a way so that when you view a list of installed programs, they will show up.  Using Microsoft Windows's Control Panel (last I checked... though I keep reading that Microsoft wants to migrate such functionility), you could go to the icon that says "Programs" (in Windows 95, it was called something like "Add or Remove Programs", while I think newer versions are called something like "Software/Programs", so who knows just what it is called in the version of Windows you use, but look for something named "Programs"), and then in that list, choose the program from the list and then choose "Uninstall".  Then, Microsoft Windows will run the listed "Uninstaller" program, which will hopefully do a nice job of removing the program and possibly also removing some related data, while not causing problems.
I'm not sure if you were trying to have Windows run the Uninstaller, or maybe the Git installer actually checks if Git is already listed as an installed program, but somehow that Uninstaller program at E:\Git\unins000.exe is trying to get run.  Unfortunately for that attempt, E:\Git\unins000.exe apparently does not exist yet.
So, using my terminology, you may have already deleted Git (by removing all of E:\Git, perhaps), but yet Microsoft Windows still remembers that Git was installed once, and that Git had an Uninstaller at E:\Git\unins000.exe.  (And if Git's installer is checking for such details, then Git's installer is likely getting that information from Microsoft Windows.)
The solution is to correct/update the information (likely by just deleting the related information) that Microsoft Windows has about the old Git installation.  That can be done.  I don't recall how off-hand, but I've done such before.  (Maybe editing the Registry.)  If you still want this done (and that might be helpful), please search for a guide specific to doing that, and if you have further questions, then make a new question focused on just that topic.
(I'm not quite done with this answer yet, but will save the draft that I wrote so far, so I don't lose it if my browser crashes, and so others may see this answer has been started.)
Installing Git
The question's topic of "Issues with deleting and reinstalling git completely" indicates there is a desire to get Git installed.
https://www.siteground.com/kb/install-git-windows-machine/ indicates that the installation process should ask where Git should be installed.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50106122/4411648 shows information on how to specify a location from the command line.  Maybe if you do this, Git's installer might just skip the step of trying to uninstall first?  I'm not sure, but you may wish to try that.
You might also find some ideas from other sources, including:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682006/how-to-uninstall-git-for-windows-re-install-in-new-place
https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows/c/z-Kb7lDT3DQ

Summary

If you have further questions, please see if there are other related resources.  e.g.,
Having difficulty uninstalling git from Windows computer discusses an uninstaller.
If, after reviewing such resources, you feel like you do need to ask a new question, then it is probably a good idea to reference the related details in your new question.  Please try your best to keep questions limited to one topic, so that you will hopefully get either one clear answer, or multiple clear alternative solutions, which provide answers to just a single topic.  Doing so may help prevent having downvoted/closed questions.


(My questinos first "edit", made at about 6 minutes before this comment, was really me just finishing off a partially-completed answer that I had posted first.)

I know I might come across as harping heavily about the idea of just having a single topic. Just to show this wasn't just my own preferences speaking, I will point out this more official page https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask which discourages vagueness. Please don't beat yourself up too much for posting a question which wasn't perfect. My own intro to Stack Exchange was pretty rough, due to not seeing a detailed enough guide early on.  I'm not trying to be mean.  (I wrote all this to be helpful.)  I recommend just trying to apply what was said, as that helps the process of us giving help.

got it man! Thanks a lot! I'll go through the site before asking a question again.

will do. my bad
